# Kafka Streams: Object creation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say we have the DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG set to Serdes.ByteArraySerde, and assuming no further override specified in the topology and the default one is being used, would it create a new object of type byte[] array for each message that is being deserialized from the topic?  Also, is this behavior applicable when retrieving from the state store, meaning will it create new object of type byte[] array?

OR will it re-use the same object corresponding to each stream threads?

Comment: Kafka Streams does no re-use the object, but creates a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka streams uses serdes to serialize/deserialize objects whenever they need to be persistent or read from, for example, state stores. To work with such objects within the kafka-stream flow you normally define a DTO, there may be different DTOs and normally one by default, the default DTO is used if not otherwise specified. There are different techniques to achieve this, with its pros and cons, one way that can meet your needs would be to use ObjectMapper for example. Using Serdes.ByteArraySerde does not seem very useful unless you want to work at byte level, rather than at the level of an object defined in a class as dto.

Comment: Hi jmostalet,I am good with the above understanding, but my question was related to the object creation as every record from Kafka will be translated into new DTO object. My question is that would it be possible to re-usage the same object to hold different records being processed sequentially within each stream thread

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood what your question is. You define a DTO class and kafka will create a new instance of that class in the deserializer every time it is needed, every object is a record and you have to process within your topology a stream of records.

Comment: Topic -> Partition 0 -> Thread 1 -> Serializer/Deserializer.  In this scenario, we know a single thread can process only one record at a time.  I was wondering if there is a way to just use same object for each record, that is to keep re-initializing the same object (DTO) for various records as opposed to new object for each record, since a given thread will only process record at a time.  Likewise, each thread can have one object (DTO).